# React 18 useState resets array in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a series of checkboxes that need to push their name into a state array when checked, and remove their name when they are unchecked. No matter what I do, checking any sets the array to contain only that checkbox's name.

```js
const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=> {
    // Log selectedItems out every time it changes.
    console.log(selectedItems) // Always only the last selected checkbox name, no others.
}, [selectedItems])

const onCheckChange = e=> {
    console.log(e.target.name, e.target.checked) // Are as expected, the name and value.
    if (e.target.checked) {
        setSelectedItems(prev=> [...prev, e.target.name])
        // setSelectedItems([...selectedItems, e.target.name]) // Same result.
    } else {
        setSelectedItems( prev=> prev.filter(s=> s!==e.target.name) )
        // setSelectedItems(selectedItems.filter(s=> s!==e.target.name)) // Same result.
    }
}
```

Every time I check a checkbox, `selectedItems` is set to contain only the selected item's name. Every time I uncheck a checkbox, `setSelectedItems` is set to `[]`.

This seems like the most normal pattern ever, but there must be some weirdness with arrays and `useState`? Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: This needs a bit more full-fledged example.  Without seeing the usage of `onCheckChanged` (and possibly the `useState` call) it's possible to imagine several ways this _might_ be going wrong but impossible to tell which one _is_ going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in **e.target.name**. Most likely all your checkboxes are using the same name.

To fix, try to give different names, or use something else to find which checkbox was interacted (for example use **index**, with adding it as an argument of your onChange handler)

Comment: It was this! `selectedItems` needed to be managed at the component above this one, and `setSelectedItems` passed into it so the checkbox can use it as the `onChange`. Thankyou!